# jQuery.clone() using withDataAndEvents does not seem to copy data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

Ok, I've been mulling over this for a while now with no success.  According to the jQuery documentation if I use `.clone(true)` on an object that has data, then that data is copied as well when I set the `withDataAndEvents` parameters to `true`.

So for example, I have an object.  I clone it.  I update the data on the clone using `$(obj).data('mydata')['title'] = "My New Title";`.  Then when I check the *title* element on my `mydata` in the original object, it now also has a value of "My New Title".

Why is this not working for me?  What an I missing?  Or is this just not how it's supposed to work?

I have a fiddle which implements the concept that I'm trying to implement and it does the same thing.

http://jsfiddle.net/JAZ013/5ryyu0Lq/2/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same situation and solved it by extending the div1 data and assigning to div2 data.

Here the scenario is bit different as the value is `{title:'My DIV #1'}`, so the object `title` is getting referenced not copied. I solved the issue witH extending the `div1` `data`.

See the below example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myDIV1 = $('#test1');
    myDIV1.data('mydata', {title:'My DIV #1'});
    
    var myDIV2 = myDIV1.clone();
    myDIV2.data('mydata',$.extend({}, myDIV1.data('mydata')));
    myDIV2.data('mydata')['title'] = 'My DIV #2';

    myDIV1.after(myDIV2);

    myDIV1.html(myDIV1.data('mydata')['title']);
    myDIV2.html(myDIV2.data('mydata')['title']);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
<div id="test1">Thank you for trying this for me!</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/5ryyu0Lq/3/

Comment: Thanks.  Pretty much what I have ended up doing.  Although I needed it to be recursive so I wrote a function that loops through a collection of objects and extends their data then calls that same function on their children, if any.  Works well.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation for [withDataAndEvents](http://api.jquery.com/clone/#clone-withDataAndEvents), it copies the data does not make clone of it.

> A Boolean indicating whether event handlers and data should be copied
>   along with the elements.

In your case both the elements `mydata` refers to the same object so any change made to that object properties will be reflected in both the elements

Comment: Yeah, that's not what I get from the documentation.  It also says

```However, objects and arrays within element data are not copied and will continue to be shared between the cloned element and the original element. To deep copy all data, copy each one manually:``` with an example on how to do so, then it says ```As of jQuery 1.5, withDataAndEvents can be optionally enhanced with deepWithDataAndEvents  to copy the events and data for all children of the cloned element.```  So  'copy' is different to 'clone' and the fact that it appears to be used interchangeably is confusing me?